# Нужны ли знаки препинания в данном заголовке?

Tags: пунктуация

Двадцатилетний гений Боян Слат намерен очистить Мировой океан

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Знаки препинания не требуются, но возможен авторский вариант с двоеточием:

> Двадцатилетний гений: Боян Слат намерен очистить Мировой океан

В таком варианте подзаголовок после двоеточия раскрывает аспект, в котором проявляется названная автором гениальность (мол, да он просто гений:),  в то время как вариант без знаков препинания подразумевает, что именование данного человека гением - сложившаяся практика и что читателю об этом известно.

Comment: Креативный подход. Браво!

Answer (score 3):

Двадцатилетний гений Боян Слат намерен очистить Мировой океан.

**Знаки препинания не нужны,** пред именем собственным стоит распространенное приложение.

Вариант с обособлением имени будет иметь **значение уточнения**, но это плохо согласуется с сочетанием "двадцатилетний гений" по семантике.